# How to delete part of a string by matching conditions?

Tags: python

I have many addresses information, such as:

```
123 1st Ave Apt501, Flushing, New York, 00000, USA
234 West 20th Street 1A, New York, New York, 11111, USA
345 North 100st Street Apt. 110, New York, New York, 22222, USA
```

I would like to get the street information. So, I am wondering how can I delete the apartment information after "Ave", and "Street"?

So, the addresses will be cleaned as:

```
123 1st Ave, Flushing, New York, 00000, USA
234 West 20th Street, New York, New York, 11111, USA
345 North 100st Street, New York, New York, 22222, USA
```

Or the data can be cleaned as:

```
123 1st Ave
234 West 20th Street
345 North 100st Street
```

This is the code I tried. However, I was not able to remove apartment information not including "apt".

```
conditions = [df.address.str.contains('Apt')]
choices = [df.address.apply(lambda x: x[x.find('Apt'):])]
df['apt'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = '')
choices2 = [df.address.apply(lambda x: x[:x.find('Apt')])]
df['address'] = np.select(conditions, choices2, default = df.address)
```

Comment: You probably want to use regular expressions to extract the pieces of information you need, then you can put them back together however you want.

Comment: You could also split on `,` from the looks of your data format to make this easier by splitting into street, city, state, zip, country.

Comment: But what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, the way I did was identifying substrings "Apt" and deleting substring starting with "Apt", but this cannot identify the situation without "Apt".

Comment: If you've tried something, show your code in your question. You can edit it to add details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap all the addresses in a list and use a split to separate each element in the address so you can access street information by index 0.

```
addresses  = ['123 1st Ave, Flushing, New York, 00000, USA', '234 West 20th Street, New York, New York, 11111, USA',
        '345 North 100st Street, New York, New York, 22222, USA']

for s in addresses:
    print(s.split(',')[0])
```

Output

```
123 1st Ave
234 West 20th Street
345 North 100st Street
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, limit your split to _once_. `s.split(',', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

To get the second option, I'd split at comma first and then process the first item with a regular expression.

```py
df['street'] = (df.address
       .str.split(',') # split at ,
       .str[0] # get the first element
       .str.replace('(Apt[.\s]*|Street\s+)\d+\w?$',
       '')
       )
```

The regular expression matches

- `Apt` followed by zero or more dots or whitespace OR
- `Street` followed by whitespace
- one or more integers
- an optional letter

and all that at the end of the string (`$`).

The pattern might need some tweaking but gives the right result for the example.

Comment: This gives a really example! Thanks!